# Show trailing icon only on one item from a ListTile on Click in flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, listtile

Basically I want the user to select only 1 age from a list, and show **Trailing Icon** on that clicked `ListTile` and when user click on other `ListTile`, that **Trailing Icon** should shift to that tile.

> What I'm getting

[image: img1]

> What I want

[image: img2]

> My `ListView` Code:

```
ListView.separated(
  itemCount: ageList.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return ItemWidget(
      item: ageList[index],
    );
  },
  separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Divider(height: 0);
  },
),
```

> My List Tile Code

```
 return ListTile(
  onTap: () {
    print("${widget.item.name} pressed");
    setState(() {
      // widget.item.clicked = !widget.item.clicked;
    });
    widget.item.clicked = !widget.item.clicked;
  },
  title: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 6.0),
    child: Text(widget.item.name),
  ),
  trailing: Visibility(
    visible:  widget.item.clicked == null ? false : widget.item.clicked,
    child: Icon(
      Icons.done,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you don't need to save the selection state on object level. You can handle it by using a single variable of int type as

```
int selectedAge = -1;
  _ageList(index){
    return ListTile(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          selectedAge = index;
        });
      },
      title: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 6.0),
        child: Text(widget.item.name),
      ),
      trailing: Visibility(
        visible:  selectedAge == index,
        child: Icon(
          Icons.done,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: it's working same as mine, all the tiles are being selected – 
I want to select only one tile

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you and one thing used

Declare int var and your list:

```
int? tappedIndex; 

  List<String> litems = [
    "Counter No 1",
    "Counter No 2",
    "Counter No 3",
    "Counter No 4"
  ];
```

Declare initState() method

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tappedIndex = 0;
  }
```

Your Widget:

```
 return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: litems.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
                child: ListTile(
              trailing: Visibility(
                visible: tappedIndex == index,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.done,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),
              title: Text(litems[index]),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  tappedIndex = index;
                });
              },
            ));
          }),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Your Result screen->  [image]

Comment: @Ravibdra my `ListView` is in different class and my `ListTile` is in different, above code will not work there i think.

Comment: its working on my machine what was the problem are you test my answer?

Comment: it's working same as mine, all the tiles are being selected

Comment: I want to select only one tile

Answer (score 0):

We can create a nullable variable for a selected Item. And while `trailing` is nullable, we don't need `visibilty` widget to handle it. Here is a sample demo.

```dart
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  int? selectedIndex;

  final ageList = List.generate(22, (index) => index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.separated(
      itemCount: ageList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              selectedIndex = index;
            });
          },
          title: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 6.0),
            child: Text(ageList[index].toString()),
          ),
          trailing: index == selectedIndex
              ? const Icon(
                  Icons.done,
                  color: Colors.white,
                )
              : null,
        );
      },
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Divider(height: 0);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm testing on `deepPurple` Scaffold  backgroundColor.

Comment: Hi, using this method, now none of the `ListTile` is being selected.

Comment: It should after tapping one, because initially user didn't select any. Did you test my widget separately ?

Comment: no, I changed my code according to yours

Comment: if I'm not wrong, you are missing something on your snippet.  check again.